# The mouse 'wheel' event in Firefox freeze on full scroll but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, mousewheel

I have an issue with the mouse event with Firefox. I want to create a website made of slides as Fullpage.js does but I do not want to use it and I chose to implements the system myself. But with Firefox, the scrolling event seems to be stopped with several triggered mouse wheel events and, therefore, freezing animation.

I made an Angular directive that triggers the 'wheel' event and call with a throttle time the function that defines the scroll direction.

Then, I created a component that calls that directive and defines what to do with its result.

This is how my directive works

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appMouseWheel]' })
export class MouseWheelDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() mouseWheelUp = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() mouseWheelDown = new EventEmitter();


  private mouse = new Subject<any>();
  private mouseObs = this.mouse.asObservable();

  @HostListener('wheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheel(event: any) {
    console.log('debounce');
    event.preventDefault();
    this.mouse.next(event);
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.mouseObs.pipe(throttleTime(1000)).subscribe(x => this.mouseWheelFunc(x));
  }

  public mouseWheelFunc(event: any) {
    const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (-event.deltaY || -event.detail)));

    if (delta > 0) {
      this.mouseWheelUp.emit(event);
    } else if (delta < 0) {
      this.mouseWheelDown.emit(event);
    }

    if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly with Chrome but freezes with Firefox as you can see right here : http://ukeep.monteil.co

If anyone has the answer, I'll be grateful!

Comment: Any error in firefox browser?

Comment: Nope, as you can see with the given link. You can make it works with Firefox with a 'little scroll' step by step with your mouse but it is not the expected behaviour :/